# How does the syntax of this bind function to compose two debugging functions work?

Tags: haskell, bind, monads, higher-order-functions

I am working through [this tutorial on how I could have implemented Monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) by working through the concepts.

Exercise 1 is to write a bind function which can glue together two functions using this function signature:

```
bind :: (Float -> (Float,String)) -> ((Float,String) -> (Float,String))
```

I understand the concept but I was struggling to write it myself so I had a look at the answer:

```
bind f' (gx,gs) = let (fx,fs) = f' gx in (fx,gs++fs)
```

I don't really understand the syntax of the answer, I understand the concept of pattern matching but I haven't really come across functions which are returning functions inline like this before. Can someone break down how exactly the syntax of this function works?

I also see that this was written in 2006 so I wondered if there would be any differences in how you would write this function since then?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you don't understand in this expression. It certainly doesn't "return a function inline". All I see is a `let ... in` expression which uses pattern matching, which here is just a readable shorthand for applying `f'` and extracting the two parts of the resulting pair.

Comment: @RobinZigmond  thanks for the reply. I think my issue is that I don't 100% understand the `let .... in` syntax here. I think I understand now from your answer but I just want to check with you. So the `let ... in` expression is executing `f' gx` and then setting the `fx` and `fs` variables to the output of that function using pattern matching?

Comment: @RobinZigmond But then it looks to me like the bind function is taking in two arguments, one function and one pair which is pattern matched into `gx` and `gs`. But from the function signature it looks like the bind function is only taking one parameter, a function which takes an `Float` and returns a `(Float,String)` pair

Comment: That's because of function currying. A function of two arguments, `a -> b -> c`, is identical to a function that takes just the first argument and returns another function which takes the second: `a -> (b -> c)`

Comment: @RobinZigmond I think I understand this now. So the function signature could be instead written as `bind :: (Float -> (Float,String)) -> (Float,String) -> (Float,String)`. Which now makes complete sense. 
I think my initial confusions seems to be stemming from encountering multiple concepts that I am still fairly new to at the same time. Thanks for your help

Comment: `bind f' (gx,gs) = let { (fx,fs) = f' gx } in (fx,gs++fs)` should be clear(er).

Comment: also, `foo x y = bar` is the same as `foo x = (\ y -> bar)` is the same as `foo = (\x -> (\y -> bar))` the same as `foo = (\x y -> bar)`.